# counting function on data frame in R

Tags: r, count, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
> Mice
        Blood  States  Minute
1       0.875     X0 0.8352569
2       0.875     A2 0.7551901
3       0.625     X0 1.4508139
4       0.625     A1 0.7876343
5       0.375     X0 1.1345252
6       0.125     X0 0.8699363
7       0.375     X0 0.9378742
8       1.125     H1 0.9769522
9       0.625     X0 0.4716321
10      0.875     H1 0.9935999
11      0.625     X0 1.0025917
12      0.375     A1 1.0703999
13      0.375     X0 1.3044854
14      0.875     H1 0.6720436
15      0.875     A1 1.0431863
```

So every mouse has some value of drugs in their "Blood", and their "State" is checked. This is just a piece of my data frame, but the mice can be in 4 different states. "Minute" is whenever something occurs to the mice, does not matter what.

For every value of "Blood", the mice can be in either of the 4 different states, and I want to count how many observations I have in each category.

The count() function with both columns Blood and States did not work because "States" is a factor column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To operate on factor levels, you can use `tapply` or `by`. If you have discrete scale for `Mice$Blood`, convert it to a factor as well:

```
> by(mice$States, as.factor(mice$Blood), function(x) summary(factor(x)))

as.factor(mice$Blood): 0.125
X0 
 1 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
as.factor(mice$Blood): 0.375
A1 X0 
 1  3 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
as.factor(mice$Blood): 0.625
A1 X0 
 1  3 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
as.factor(mice$Blood): 0.875
A1 A2 H1 X0 
 1  1  2  1 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
as.factor(mice$Blood): 1.125
H1 
 1
```

The returned object is a list, so you may capture it and use for your purposes.